# How to repair holes in concrete driveway?

Tags: concrete, driveway, hole-repair

I have a concrete driveway that is chipping.  Is there any good options to fill these chipped areas?

Comment: It depends how bad it is chipping. You could try mortar or self leveling concrete. If you use mortar add some of the additive acrylic fortifier. It helps by making it stickier and makes it contract and expand more like the concrete that is down already to prevent future cracking.

Comment: The chips are about the size of a quarter and about 1/4" to 1/2" deep.

Comment: How many of them are there ? can you post a picture ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Sackrete Top'n Bond - a patching cement with latex additive.  It's great for patching concrete, adheres well and is quite strong.  It's easy to apply and is intended for this use.  Just check color first.